# How to get EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME from HLS stream with gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, http-live-streaming

I have pipeline that successfully reads HLS stream, and Im attempting to get tag with help of dicoverer structures:

```c
    tags = gst_discoverer_info_get_tags(info);
    gchar * value = nullptr;
    gboolean retv = gst_tag_list_get_string(tags, "EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME", &value);
    if ( value ) {
           log_gst.log("EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME: {}", value);
            g_free(value);
 }
```

But this code cannot retrieve tag.
In the end, I need to be able to get timestamp for current frame, I can only get PTS(timestamp from the start of the stream), but I need to calculate exact datetime when stream was started.

Answer (score 2):

The EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME HLS tag was added to the hlsdemux as a tag event in GStreamer 1.22.

Not sure what GStreamer version you're using, but you can achieve what you want by either migrating to 1.22 or backporting this feature to your GStreamer version.

Here's the original Issue: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/-/issues/195

And here's the associated Merge Request: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/merge_requests/1417

You can see those tag events in a simple pipeline like so:

```
GST_DEBUG=GST_EVENT:TRACE gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=https://mtoczko.github.io/hls-test-streams/test-program-time/playlist.m3u8 ! application/x-hls ! hlsdemux ! fakesink |& grep tag
```

You can then parse those tag events in your GStreamer element or GStreamer application to extract the datetime you're looking for.